# Mongo database disconnects when using docker

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am using docker compose with my app and are trying to connect mongodb to the server. When i run my app locally outside of docker i get this as output(works as intended)

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server running
Mongoose connected to db...
Mongodb connected....
```

When i run the **docker-compose up** command and the server runs in the container i get this output

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
docker-server  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
docker-server  | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
docker-server  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
docker-server  | [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
docker-server  | Works
docker-server  | Works
docker-server  | Mongoose connection is disconnected...
```

After a while the mongoose **disconnects**.

My **package.json** is

```
{
  "name": "make-me-a-sandwich",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "This is the Swagger 2.0 API for Web Architectures course group project work.        ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "swagger"
  ],
  "license": "Unlicense",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.2.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.3.0",
    "swagger-tools": "0.10.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
}
```

}

My **index.js** file is

```
const http = require('http');
const connect = require('./models/db');

const PORT = 80;
const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

const { url, method, headers } = request;
const filePath = new URL(url, `http://${headers.host}`).pathname;

if (filePath === '/' && method.toUpperCase() === 'GET') {
    console.log("Works")
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    response.end('Hello, World! GET\n');
} else {
    response.statusCode = 200;
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    response.end('Hello, World! Teemu\n');
}

});

server.on('error', err => {
   console.error(err);
   server.close();
});

server.on('close', () => console.log('Server closed.'));

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Server running");
});
connect.connectDB();
```

**model/db.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function connectDB() {
   mongoose
       .connect('mongodb://mongo_db:27017', {
           useNewUrlParser: true,
       })
       .then(() => {
           console.log('Mongodb connected....');
       })
       .catch(err => console.log(err.message));

   mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
       console.log('Mongoose connected to db...');
   });

   mongoose.connection.on('error', err => {
       console.log(err.message);
   });

   mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
       console.log('Mongoose connection is disconnected...');
   });
};
function disconnectDB() {
    mongoose.disconnect();
}

module.exports = { connectDB, disconnectDB };
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:17.3.0

WORKDIR /server

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose** file

```
version: "3"

services:
  server-a:
    container_name: docker-server
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context:  ./backend/server-a
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    links: 
      - mongo_db
    networks:
      - backend
  mongo_db:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
networks:
  backend:
```

Help would be really appreciated. Let me also know if i can offer any other information.

Comment: It makes little sense to use nodemon in a docker container. It is used for development to restart the server when you change a source file. Since the changes are not visible to the Docker container after the build, nodemon is not useful.

Comment: Since you are exposing the mongodb ports to your host anyway, remove the server-a configuration from docker-compose and use localhost:27017 for connecting with mongoose.

Comment: I intend to add volumes so i ican see the changes in container but at them moment just trying to fix the database disconnect. Also everything must be in docker compose for this project no local database or server. @Clashsoft

Comment: The two containers are on different `networks:` and so they can't communicate.  Does it help to delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the file, along with the obsolete `links:` setting?

Comment: Yeah that seemed to be it but i need to have my backend in the network. How can implement it so that the database can communicate with the backend and doesnt disconnect @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different containers need to be on the same Compose network to communicate.  If a service doesn't have a `networks:` block, Compose automatically attaches it to a `default` network.  So in your example, the `server-a` container is only on the `backend` network, but the `mongo_db` container is only on the `default` network, and that's why they can't communicate.

The easiest way to resolve this is to delete *all* of the `networks:` blocks in the file.  Then Compose will attach all of the containers to the `default` network.  Removing other unnecessary options, you could reduce this Compose file to just

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  server-a:
    build: ./backend/server-a
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
  mongo_db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

In a comment you suggest that it's important to keep a second named network.  If that's the case, then you need to make sure the database container also has a `networks:` block that names a network in common with the application container.